# p:galleria does not show images

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to use Primefaces galleria. I have seen galleria but I am not able to display images. I have tried these following codes:

**Galleria.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
<p:galleria value="#{imagesView.images}" var="image" panelWidth="600" panelHeight="400" showCaption="true">
    <p:graphicImage name="/resources/images/#{image}"/>
</p:galleria>
```

**Galleria.java**

```
@ManagedBean
public class ImagesView {
    private List<String> images;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        images = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            images.add("nature" + i + ".jpg");
        }
    }
    public List<String> getImages() {
        return images;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you put the images in your project?

Comment: Web Content - resources - images - (image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg)

Comment: Check the thing called a browser developer tool

Answer (score 0):

Use `name` attribute

`<p:graphicImage name="images/#{image}"/>`

Comment: I tried it but still not

Comment: @sara Edited my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, I still don't see images

Comment: Are your images in src -> main -> webapp -> resources -> images? Because it worked for me for this structure.

Comment: my images in package->Web Content -> resources -> images -> (image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg)

Comment: my xhtml file in package->Web Content-> Galleria.xhtml

Comment: I'm using Maven archetype so I can't help you but one more thing - in code you use image names like `natureX.jpg` but in comments you type `imageX.jpg`. Didn't you mix it?

Comment: ok.Thank you so much for your helps

Comment: Do you have any errors in console (`F12`) when opening the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the image names like this:

```
images.add("images/nature" + i + ".jpg");
```

Then just change the `p:graphicImage` definition:

```
<p:graphicImage name="#{resource[image]}"/>
```

It should then map the image name properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem which I solved by dong following changes getting help from internet.

I know this one is old one but i am posting this for others who are facing the same issue.

you need to create ***resources*** folder and under that create one ***images*** folder and put all the images inside that.

Comment: It should be created under webcontent folder.